# Embedding Videos in my Django site

Tags: youtube-api, django-1.10

I have no idea about embedding videos in Django.
I am storing my videos in a database.
I need to do embedding, displaying and deleting my videos in my Django site.

Can any one give a right direction for do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Hi this question is a little tricky.

Django is basically a framework for creating web apps using python, you are saying you already have a Django website and you are not explaining what you have, also not specifying what format you have for your videos (e.g.: binary? or folder paths? or urls?) so there are plenty options.

Here is a hint, what about creating a SPA (single page architecture) HTML/CSS3/JS with angularJS to make calls to your API/website (django)

- Create folder name called "static" in your root django project folder
- Create folder name called "templates" in your root django project folder
- Inside "static" add following structure

  - images
  - js
  - css
- Inside "templates" add your html file

  - index.html

1) Go to your settings.py and add following paths

- Create 3 static config vars for your HTML (**templates**) and CSS/JS/IMG/VIDEOS (**static**) folders

  ```
  STATICFILES_DIRS=['/your_home_path/your_project/static/']
  STATIC_URL = '/static/'
  TEMPLATES_PATH = '/your_home_path/your_project/templates/'
  ```
- Modify your **TEMPLATES** static var to use **TEMPLATES_PATH**

  ```
  TEMPLATES = [
  {
      'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
      'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_PATH],
      'APP_DIRS': True,
      'OPTIONS': {
          'context_processors': [
              'django.template.context_processors.debug',
              'django.template.context_processors.request',
              'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
              'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
          ],
      },
  },
  ```

  ]

2) Go to you urls.py file and register your template HTML file so it can be used as the website layout also create a new route for test a new controller/action

```
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
url(r'testingwebsite/v1/api/test/action$', action_controller_name),
```

3) Go to your views.py file and add controller action code so you can do whatever you want (**GET/UPDATE/DELETE** a video)

```
def action_controller_name(request):
    #Your_code_here: execute py scripts or call API or connect to DB
    #return json
    return HttpResponse(out, content_type="application/json")
```

4) Include required libraries in your views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
#static files import
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

***If you have videos on your database in binary format***

Read them from the database and create a temp file in a temp folder so you can add video html tag to your django template

***If instead you have urls or file paths of this videos***

Read them from the database so you can add video html tag to your django template

How to include static folder's content files(videos/images/css/js/etc) in your HTML?

```
{% static "images/logo.png" %}
{% static "videos/myvideo.mp4" %}
```

**Video tag sample**

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="{% static "videos/myvideo.mp4" %}" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="{% static "videos/myvideo.ogg" %}" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

**Img tag sample**

```
<img alt="majordomo_logo" src="{% static "images/logo.png" %}" class="img-circle" width="60">
```

**You could do the same for a video*

How to trigger action of your angularJS app/controller/service on your HTML?

- Create a function "selectEntity()" inside your controller then call it from your HTML like this:

  ```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-theme" ng-click="selectEntity()">Off</button>
  ```

How to use static files on your python code?
e.g.: execute python script inside "static" folder

```
command="bash " + settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0] + "pyscripts/clean-memory-mock.sh"

p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

out, err = p.communicate()

print out
```

Hope this helps!